# Why is virtual velocity defined with only variation in generalized velocities?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, variational-principle, power, rigid-body-dynamics

[Jourdain's principle](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Jourdain_principle) employed in Vehicle Dynamics (Road Vehicle Dynamics, Georg Rill) states that virtual power of $k$ rigid bodies vanishes, i.e.

$$ \sum\limits_1^k \delta v_i(y,z)\cdot F_i^c(y,z) + \delta \omega_i(y,z) \cdot T_i^c(y,z) = 0,$$

where $y$ is the vector of generalized coordinates, $z$ the vector of generalized velocities and $v,\omega,F,T$ represents velocity, angular velocity, constraint forces and constraint torques respectively.

The virtual velocity and virtual angular velocity is defined as

$$\delta v_i = \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial z} \delta z,~~\delta \omega_i = \frac{\partial \omega_i}{\partial z} \delta z .$$

Why are the virtual velocities defined as above, when the velocities are a function of both generalized velocities and generalized coordinates?

Note: For the sake of simplicity, when compared to the cited book, I have dropped subscripts related to reference frame.

Comment: Wow, what a shitty notation and introduction to principle of virtual works. I'll add an answer in the evening (Central Europe Time)

Comment: If you work with generalized coordinate , you are already eliminated the constrained equations

Comment: It should be $\delta v_i = \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial z_j} \delta z_j,~~\delta \omega_i = \frac{\partial \omega_i}{\partial z_j} \delta z_j .$$